# How to I send an Id After creating a new record Django?

Tags: python, django

Good evening I'm doing an application with django and I need that after creating a record I address with HttpresponseRedirect taking the id of this new record to a new view and a different template.

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', beneficiario, name='beneficiario'),
    url(r'^beneficiario_create/(?P<id>\d+)/$', beneficiario_create,    name='beneficiario_create'),    
]
```

wiews.py

```
def datosBasicos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        beneficiario = Beneficiario()
        beneficiario.numeroDocumento = request.POST['numeroDocumento']
        beneficiario.nombreUno = request.POST['nombreUno']
        beneficiario.save()
        ben = Beneficiario.objects.get(id=beneficiario.id)
        messages.success(request, validator.getMessage())
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/beneficiario/beneficiario_create/%d/'%ben.id)
    return render(request,'datosBasicos.html', informacion)

def beneficiario_create(request, id):
    beneficiario = Beneficiario.objects.get(id = id)
    return render(request,'beneficiario_create.html')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question; but try building the url with [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), like this `return redirect('beneficiario_create', id=beneficiario.pk)`

Comment: Get this error `Reverse for 'beneficiario_create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['beneficiario/beneficiario_create/(?P<id_ben>\\d+)/$']`

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to (and shouldn't really) use a raw URL in `HttpResponseRedirect`, you can you use [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) which allows you to include URL kwargs. For example:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('beneficiario_create', kwargs={'id': ben.id))
```

To combine the `reverse` with the `HttpResponseRedirect`, you can use the django shortcut method `redirect` like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect('beneficiario_create', id=ben.id)
```

Comment: You can just use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: Get this error `Reverse for 'beneficiario_create' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['beneficiario/beneficiario_create/(?P<id_ben>\\d+)/$']`

Comment: Well, you changed the URL kwarg, so now it should be `id_ben=ben.id`